# Capybara Selenium reuse existing browser session, instead of opening new windows?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara

In Capybara, How can I reuse existing browser to continue run step next. Instead of star a new session and open a new windown and next run a ton of step before.

For example :
First:

```
session =  Capybara::Session.new(:headless_chrome, Capybara.app)
session.open(url)
session.click(...)
sesion.quit()
```

Second Time:

```
session =  ...#retry the first session state
sesion.do_something()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybara is designed as a testing tool, where you want every test to be completely independent of other tests.  Because of that it has no support for storing/reloading a session, and uses a fresh browser instance (data-dir, etc) for each session. To prevent creation of a completely new browser setup every time you create a new session you could pass your own `--user-data-dir=<some_directory>` option when registering your Capybara driver, but it's not Capybara supported usage (and would really not be a good idea if you're actually doing testing rather than web scraping). Another option if all you really want is the cookies retained would be something like https://github.com/kyamaguchi/capybara-sessionkeeper (again bad idea if you're testing since it couples tests to each other).

Comment: Thanks.
Btw: use --user-data-dir=<some_directory> when starting new session browser seem to be lost authorization. Like https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/921